# How to get the value of an attribute from XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Sorry if this seems like an easy question, but I've started pulling hair out on this...

I have a XML file which looks like this...

```
<VAR VarNum="90">
  <option>1</option>
</VAR>
```

I'm trying to get the **VarNum**.

So far I've been successful using the follow code to get the other information:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
$option=$xml->option;
```

I just can't get VarNum (the attribute value I think?)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the attribute's value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be able to get this using [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-attributes.php)

Try this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
foreach($xml->Var[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

That will show you all the name/value attributes for the first `foo` element.  It's an associative array, so you can do this as well:

```
$attr = $xml->Var[0]->attributes();
echo $attr['VarNum'];
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. When I try this I get the following error - "Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object"

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this working (it was a syntax error - doh!)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 14):

What about using `$xml['VarNum']` ?

Like this :

```
$str = <<<XML
<VAR VarNum="90">
  <option>1</option>
</VAR>
XML;

$xml=simplexml_load_string($str);
$option=$xml->option;

var_dump((string)$xml['VarNum']);
```

(I've used `simplexml_load_string` because I've pasted your XML into a string, instead of creating a file ; what you are doing with `simplexml_load_file` is fine, in your case !)

Will get you

```
string '90' (length=2)
```

With simpleXML, you access attributes with an array syntax.

And you have to cast to a string to get the value, and not and instance of `SimpleXMLElement`

For instance, see **example #5** of [Basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) in the manual :-)

Comment: Note: the casting to (string) in the example.

Comment: @null : (nice nichname, by the way ^^) : Thanks! I eddited to add that (and a couple more precisions)

Comment: The cast to string is very important when accessing the attributes of a node.  We saw some funky behavior (empty value) when we failed to include the cast.

Answer (score 3):

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [uri] => https://abcd.com:1234/abc/cst/2/
                        [id] => 2
                    )

                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [first] => abcd
                        [last] => efg
                    )

                [company] => abc SOLUTION
                [email] => abc@xyz.com
                [homepage] => WWW.abcxyz.COM
                [phone_numbers] => Array
                    (
                        [phone_number] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [main] => true
                                        [type] => work
                                        [list_order] => 1
                                        [number] => +919876543210
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [main] => false
                                        [type] => mobile
                                        [list_order] => 2
                                        [number] => +919876543210
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [photo] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [uri] => https://abcd.com:1234/abc/cst/2/cust_photo/
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I applied the below code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($array);
```

but it is not use full i want all the data in single array in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$xml->attributes()['YourPropertyName']; //check property case also
```