# Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having a problem accessing the `@attribute` section of my SimpleXML object.  When I `var_dump` the entire object, I get the correct output, and when I `var_dump` the rest of the object (the nested tags), I get the correct output, but when I follow the docs and `var_dump` `$xml->OFFICE->{'@attributes'}`, I get an empty object, despite the fact that the first `var_dump` clearly shows that there are attributes to output.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here/how I can make this work?

Comment: var_dump() is misleading, when it comes to SimpleXML.  Don't take its output literally.  Also, cant you access attributes using array access? e.g. $xml->OFFICE['MyAttribute']?

Comment: if you want to use ['@attributes'] you need to cast the SimpleXMLElement to array first

Comment: Another [Access SimpleXML Attribute reference question ("How to get the value of an attribute from XML file in PHP?")](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1256796/367456)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/it/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can get the attributes of an XML element by calling the attributes() function on an XML node. You can then var_dump the return value of the function.

More info at php.net
http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes

Example code from that page:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, `$b` will be a `SimpleXMLElement` object so `print_r`and `var_dump` will give you weird things. You can cast it as a string (or whatever you like) to get around this.

Comment: Do "".$b to keep it as a string

Answer (score 162):

Try this

```
$xml->attributes()->Token
```

Comment: This has been already answered [by @Artefacto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3410579/367456).

Comment: I've tried this, and I think the page is crashing.  Bora below seems to think this is a wrong format, which I'm agreeing with at this moment..  However I've seen this (your) format mentioned multiple times.  Is there some nuance I'm missing?

Comment: @GerardONeill, I don't understand why Bora says it's wrong way of accessing the attributes, it works pretty perfect. What you may be missing is that you need to call `attributes()` on the object corresponding the the right tag in your XML. Like if you have `<root><tag attr="a">b</tag></root>` then you need to do `$xml->tag->attributes()->attr` to access it.

Comment: This returns null for me, likely not because the answer is wrong, but because the answer lacks sufficient explanation for me to use it correctly.

Comment: when I call like this - I do not get attribute value, I get SimpleXMLElement which containes 0="2001" (2001 is my value). If I use that 0 - $xml->Policy->CommlPolicy->CommlCoverage[0]->attributes()->id[0] then I againg get same 0="2001". What is that?

Comment: why this is not the chosen answer, the last time I lost several hours because I saw higher that not the most correct answer, I had to dig to the solution by reading full http://www.sitepoint.com/parsing-xml-with-simplexml/ article, `current($xml->attributes(current($xml->getNamespaces(true)))->noNamespaceSchemaLocation)` for retrieving concretely the schema atribute

Answer (score 73):

I used before so many times for getting `@attributes` like below and it was a little bit longer.

```
$att = $xml->attributes();
echo $att['field'];
```

It should be more easy and you can get attributes following format only at once:

#### Standard Way - Array-Access Attributes (AAA)

```
$xml['field'];
```

Other alternatives are:

#### Right & Quick Format

```
$xml->attributes()->{'field'};
```

#### Wrong Formats

```
$xml->attributes()->field;
$xml->{"@attributes"}->field;
$xml->attributes('field');
$xml->attributes()['field'];
$xml->attributes->['field'];
```

Comment: I'm agreeing with your first of your wrong formats because I'm getting a page crash -- however multiple people are claiming this works.  Any explanation or nuance about this?

Comment: "Wrong formats" work. I always use first example. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Technically, `$xml->attributes()->{'field'}`, `$xml->attributes()->field`, and `$f='field'; $xml->attributes()->$f;` are the same. See no reason why one is a right format and another is wrong.

Comment: $xml->attributes()->{'field'} is correct because it's safe to use with special characters in attribute name (i.e "data-attr"). $xml->attributes()->field works only for attributes which are single alphanumeric words

Comment: Getting SimpleXMLElement when using both correct options.

Comment: had to explicitly cast to `string` in order to get `string` instead of `SimpleXMLElement`. `(string) $xml->attributes()['attr']`

Answer (score 45):

```
$xml = <<<XML
<root>
<elem attrib="value" />
</root>
XML;

$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$attrs = $sxml->elem->attributes();
echo $attrs["attrib"]; //or just $sxml->elem["attrib"]
```

Use [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Truth is, the SimpleXMLElement [`get_properties`](http://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects#get_properties) handler lies big time. There's no property named "@attributes", so you can't do `$sxml->elem->{"@attributes"}["attrib"]`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining *why* SimpleXML behaves in this bizarre way (the `get_properties` handler). Very interesting.

Comment: Getting SimpleXMLElement when doing this instead of value

Answer (score 17):

You can just do:

```
echo $xml['token'];
```

Comment: It's jus this lol

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for a list of these attributes though, XPath will be your friend

```
print_r($xml->xpath('@token'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I have a unique build (stuck with Gentoo for the moment) of PHP 5.5, and what I found was that

```
 $xml->tagName['attribute']
```

was the only solution that worked.  I tried all of Bora's methods above, including the 'Right & Quick' format, and they all failed.

The fact that this is the easiest format is a plus, but didn't enjoy thinking I was insane trying all of the formats others were saying worked.

Njoy for what its worth (did I mention unique build?).

Comment: I would normally recommend to use array notation for attributes for the attributes in the same namespace of the element  their part of. I'd say it's the easiest format (as you coin it) for a reason. array-access with a named key = attribute with simplexml element.

Answer (score 4):

It helped me to convert the result of simplexml_load_file($file) into a JSON Structure and decode it back:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$token.xml");
$json = json_encode($xml);
$xml_fixed = json_decode($json);

$try1 = $xml->structure->{"@attributes"}['value'];
print_r($try1);

>> result: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

$try2 = $xml_fixed->structure->{"@attributes"}['value'];
print_r($try2);

>> result: stdClass Object
(
    [key] => value
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to extract string (just Song title and Artist name)  from external xml file: https://nostalgicfm.ro/NowOnAir.xml
This form of xml:

```
 <Schedule System="Jazler">
     <Event status="happening" startTime="20:31:20" eventType="song">
        <Announcement Display=""/>
      <Song title="Let It Be ">
       <Artist name="Beatles">
        <Media runTime="265.186"/>
        <Expire Time="20:35:45"/>
       </Artist>
      </Song>
     </Event>
    </Schedule>
```

I try this code PHP but i don't know how to extract name & title...like "Beatles - Let It Be"

```
  <?php
    $url = "https://nostalgicfm.ro/NowOnAir.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    print_r($xml);
    ?>
```

Result is an Oject:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [System] => Jazler ) [Event] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [status] => happening [startTime] => 20:51:21 [eventType] => song ) [Announcement] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Display] => ) ) [Song] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [title] => If You Were A Sailboat ) [Artist] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Katie Melua ) [Media] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [runTime] => 228.732 ) ) [Expire] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Time] => 20:55:09 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself:

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://nostalgicfm.ro/NowOnAir.xml'; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
foreach ( $xml->Event->Song->Artist->attributes() as $tag => $value ); 
foreach ( $xml->Event->Song->attributes() as $tag => $value1 ) { 
echo $value." - ".$value1.PHP_EOL; } 
?>
```

Comment: explain your answer

Comment: The explanation is that I solved the problem, and the script is the one related above. The answer displayed is the desired one: "Artist - Title"

Comment: that's great petro