# Getting data out of an SimpleXML Feed

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get values of xml elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849678/how-to-get-values-of-xml-elements)

I have the following data structure but I am unsure what sequance I would use to get the `id` out of the array.

I have another XML document that works fine and I have accessed the variables like this

```
$mainPropertyUrl = simplexml_load_file("URL");
$mainPropertyDetails = $mainPropertyUrl->Attributes;
```

With the one below I have had to login via a HTTP Authentication Request and have used the following structure to generate belows code:

**Generation PHP:**

```
$oPMainUrl = 'HTTPS URI';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $oPMainUrl);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:pw");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$MainURI = simplexml_load_string($result);

$ID = $MainURI->properties->property->id;
```

I have tried the following:

**PHP:**

`property[0]->attributes[3]->id;`

**XML:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#112 (10) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["approved"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Oct 27 17:57:29 +1300 2012"
    ["last_updated"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Oct 27 17:57:29 +1300 2012"
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "278882"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your object is $xml:

```
$attr = $xml->attributes(); // returns an assoc array
echo 'ID='.$attr['id'];
```

I think you can also do this:

```
$xml['id'];
```

Comment: I will update my question with how I have done it with another XML document want to try and do it the same.