# PHP SimpleXML @attributes behavior for nodelists

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've seen this problem a few times, and would like a definitive answer.

Given this structure in xml:

```
<ByteListSet>
    <Byte Order="0">14</Byte>
</ByteListSet>
```

I am not able to access the attribute 'order'. var_dump (unsurprisingly) does not show any attributes for ByteListSet. Indeed, foreach iteration does not produce a @attributes item.

However, the following structure:

```
<ByteListSet>
    <Byte Order="0"><Value>3729</Value></Byte>
</ByteListSet>
```

Results properly in ByteListSet having a child Byte that is a SimpleXmlObject which has @attributes.

I would assume that SimpleXML is indeed picking up the @attributes from the first case, but where is it keeping them? The trouble is that in the former structure, ByteListSet produces this on var_dump of ->children():

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[25]
  public 'Byte' => string '14' (length=2)
```

if I get_object_vars() on it and var_dump each, I simply get:

```
string '14' (length=2)
```

Indicating that Byte is not being returned to me as an xml object, but just as a string; as a property of the ByteList object above it.

Order="0" is there somewhere, but I don't have access to it. How do I get to it? NOTE: ->attributes() returns, as you would expect, a blank array.

(We do not control this schema, so it can't be restructured.)

Comment: What is the exact code you are using for the dump?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> Given this structure in xml:
>
> ```
> <ByteListSet>
>     <Byte Order="0">14</Byte>
> </ByteListSet>
> ```
>
> I am not able to access the attribute 'order'.

Sure, because the attribute `order` does not exist. [XML is case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414747/367456), the attribute is named `Order` with uppercase `O` at the beginning.

Using the right attribute name allows you to access the value as outline in [Example #5 in the basic examples of the SimpleXML extension](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5289) you can find in the manual:

```
$ByteListSet = simplexml_load_string(<<<XML
<ByteListSet>
    <Byte Order="0">14</Byte>
</ByteListSet>
XML
);

echo $ByteListSet->Byte['Order']; # 0
```

Please keep in mind that what you see in `var_dump` or `print_r` is not always what you get. This is espeically true for Simplexml (compare: [*How to get values of xml elements?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2849678/367456); [*SimpleXML and print_r() - why is this empty?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3109302/367456)), however, also for other objects in PHP that make use of [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess), [`__toString()`](http://php.net/language.oop5.magic) or [`IteratorIterator`](http://php.net/class.IteratorIterator) / [`IteratorAggregate`](http://php.net/class.IteratorAggregate).

Please let me know if that answers your question. You were not very specific which existing solutions you have not understood so far, so I answered your question, but I'm not 100% if I hit the nail.