# Empty SimpleXML object?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simpleXML object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [ClosingBalance] => 5682.6500000 
    [Items] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [OpeningBalance] => 0
)
```

"Items" should be populated with data, however it seems to have returned an empty `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`.

I am not sure if its because I am reading this array incorrectly. Can someone confirm? If not how I can check what is inside the 'empty' object?

Comment: You should post both the XML data you are parsing and the PHP code you use to parse it.

Comment: This is just a common "wondering" with SimpleXML, you need to manually inspect those properties. It's asked ca. 1-10 times per day, existing Q&A should exist on this website already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get values of xml elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849678/how-to-get-values-of-xml-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to debug a SimpleXMLElement. It won't output the full XML object. If you want to see the complete XML output, use the [`asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method instead.

And for debugging this, I'd suggest using [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop)'s `simplexml_debug()` / `simplexml_tree()`  functions. You can get it here: http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering what I was doing wrong.