# parsing an xml file to a php array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xml-parsing, simplexml

I've been trying to figure out how to open an xml file and parse it as an array. But I can't seem to get it working properly. Here's the XML file:

```
<RMSAvailRateChartRS Version="1.0.0.0">
  <SoldMessage>call</SoldMessage>
  <RoomTypes>
    <RoomType>
      <RoomTypeId>10</RoomTypeId>
      <SubPropertyId>1</SubPropertyId>
      <Name>K</Name>
      <MaxOccupancy>2</MaxOccupancy>
      <Availability Id="1" Date="2013-11-04" Available="false" NoOfRoomsAvailable="0" />
      <BookingRangeAvailable>false</BookingRangeAvailable>
      <ChargeTypes>
        <ChargeType>
          <ChargeTypeId>8</ChargeTypeId>
          <Name>BAR</Name>
          <Description>Best Rate Available</Description>
          <Charge Id="1" Date="2013-11-04" Price="100.00" MinStay="1" MaxStay="25" ValidCharge="true" IncludeChildInBase="false" IncludeInfantInBase="false" Flames="false" CanArriveToday="True" PersonBase="2" ChildBase="0" InfantBase="0" />
        </ChargeType>
      </ChargeTypes>
    </RoomType>
  </RoomTypes>
</RMSAvailRateChartRS>
```

Here's my php code (to pass it as an array):

```
public static function getXML($id) {

        $file = JPATH_SITE.'/tmp/request-'.$id.'.xml';
        if (file_exists($file)) :
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($file,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);            
            return $xml;
        else :
            exit('Failed to open '.$file.'.');
        endif;

    }
```

Which works, and gives me this array:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Version] => 1.0.0.0
        )

    [SoldMessage] => call
    [RoomTypes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [RoomType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [RoomTypeId] => 10
                    [SubPropertyId] => 1
                    [Name] => K
                    [MaxOccupancy] => 2
                    [Availability] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [Id] => 1
                                    [Date] => 2013-11-04
                                    [Available] => false
                                    [NoOfRoomsAvailable] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [BookingRangeAvailable] => false
                    [ChargeTypes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [ChargeType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [ChargeTypeId] => 8
                                    [Name] => BAR
                                    [Description] => Best Rate Available
                                    [Charge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Id] => 1
                                                    [Date] => 2013-11-04
                                                    [Price] => 100.00
                                                    [MinStay] => 1
                                                    [MaxStay] => 25
                                                    [ValidCharge] => true
                                                    [IncludeChildInBase] => false
                                                    [IncludeInfantInBase] => false
                                                    [Flames] => false
                                                    [CanArriveToday] => True
                                                    [PersonBase] => 2
                                                    [ChildBase] => 0
                                                    [InfantBase] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But when I try to run through the array and echo out the information, it fails. Here's the code I'm trying to use for that:

```
foreach($xmlArr->RMSAvailRateChartRS[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
};
```

But the error I'm getting is: **Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in default.php on line 33**

Could someone please help me echoing out the details of the XML file?

Comment: It is not an array, it is an object. SimpleXML is sort of misleading here with `var_dump` and `print_r`, I suggest you to read through http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic for generic usage of SimpleXML. For concrete questions about simplexml in PHP you can also search within the tag simplexml it has some good and common questions answered, most likely anything you'll ever need with it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get values of xml elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849678/how-to-get-values-of-xml-elements)

Comment: Related comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689882/reflect-associate-array-in-browser#comment29251384_19689882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the children you'll need to use `$xmlArr->children()`.

`$xmlArr->attributes()` returns an array of the attributes of the current element.

Usage Example ([Online Demo](https://eval.in/58998)):

```
<?php
/**
 * Parsing an XML file to a PHP array
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19697845/367456
 */

$buffer = <<<BUFFER
<RMSAvailRateChartRS Version="1.0.0.0">
  <SoldMessage>call</SoldMessage>
  <RoomTypes>
    <RoomType>
      <RoomTypeId>10</RoomTypeId>
      <SubPropertyId>1</SubPropertyId>
      <Name>K</Name>
      <MaxOccupancy>2</MaxOccupancy>
      <Availability Id="1" Date="2013-11-04" Available="false" NoOfRoomsAvailable="0" />
      <BookingRangeAvailable>false</BookingRangeAvailable>
      <ChargeTypes>
        <ChargeType>
          <ChargeTypeId>8</ChargeTypeId>
          <Name>BAR</Name>
          <Description>Best Rate Available</Description>
          <Charge Id="1" Date="2013-11-04" Price="100.00" MinStay="1" MaxStay="25" ValidCharge="true" IncludeChildInBase="false" IncludeInfantInBase="false" Flames="false" CanArriveToday="True" PersonBase="2" ChildBase="0" InfantBase="0" />
        </ChargeType>
      </ChargeTypes>
    </RoomType>
  </RoomTypes>
</RMSAvailRateChartRS>
BUFFER;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

echo "Root Attributes:\n";
foreach ($xml->attributes() as $name => $value) {
    printf(" - %s = \"%s\"\n", $name, $value);
};

echo "\nRoot Children:\n";
foreach ($xml->children() as $name => $value) {
    printf(" - %s = \"%s\"\n", $name, trim($value));

    if ($name != 'RoomTypes') {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($value->RoomType->children() as $childName => $childValue) {
        printf("   - %s = \"%s\"\n", $childName, trim($childValue));
    }
}
```

Program Output:

```
Root Attributes:
 - Version = "1.0.0.0"

Root Children:
 - SoldMessage = "call"
 - RoomTypes = ""
   - RoomTypeId = "10"
   - SubPropertyId = "1"
   - Name = "K"
   - MaxOccupancy = "2"
   - Availability = ""
   - BookingRangeAvailable = "false"
   - ChargeTypes = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
foreach($xmlArr->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a."=".$b."\n";
}
```

Comment: That just returns "Version=1.0.0.0", I'm trying to get it to return all of the information from the XML file.

Comment: @SoulieBaby attributes() returns just the attributes from xml

Comment: Ok wait I figured it out, there's only attributes from certain parameters.. Thanks for your help :)