# How to get element value of xml in php array?

Tags: php, xml

My XML Response look like this:

```
<Items>
<Item>
 <ImageSets>
   <ImageSet Category="Primary">
      <SwatchImage>
         <URL>http://domain.com/img1.jpg</URL>
         <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
       </SwatchImage>
       </ImageSet>

      <ImageSet Category="Variant">
       <SwatchImage>
         <URL>http://domain.com/img2.jpg</URL>
         <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
       </SwatchImage>
       </ImageSet>

      <ImageSet Category="Variant">
       <SwatchImage>
         <URL>http://domain.com/img3.jpg</URL>
         <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
       </SwatchImage>
      </ImageSet>

      </ImageSets>
      </Item>
      </Items>
```

Now, How can i get each value of (URL) if there is more than one category??

I need to save all URL in an array, the one that is in primary and all that are in variant. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

The code should look something along the lines of:

```
simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($items as $item) {

/* For each <ImageSet> node, we echo a separate <SwatchImage><URL>. */
foreach ($Item->Item->ImageSets as $ImageSet) {
    echo $ImageSet->SwatchImage->URL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [accessing attibute from simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml).

You can access the elements like

```
$data->{'parent'}->link[0]['href'] (an example)

(That is, the attributes can be accessed using standard array notation - this definitely works on single elements, not sure if it works with the additional index into the element collection.)
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849678/how-to-get-values-of-xml-elements) for the more details ..