# How to access element attributes with SimpleXml?

Tags: php, simplexml

How can i, in php access the attributes values:

```
[photos] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [page] => 1
                [pages] => 1
                [perpage] => 24
                [total] => 18
            )
```

I have tried the following:

```
$photos->@attributes['total'] ;
$photos->{'@attributes'}['total'] ;
```

and many variations of this

Comment: Don't use `print_r()` on SimpleXMLElement. If you need to know what's inside, you use `->asXML()` on it.

Comment: Related: [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just

```
echo $photos['total'];
```

See [Example #5 Using attributes](http://de.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: can you tell me how can we loop over all the attributes?

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj: Array of all attributes: [`$photos->attributes();`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes)