# General Solution for Iterating Through PHP SimpleXMLElementObject

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse XML sequentially in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137204/parse-xml-sequentially-in-php)

I want to be able to iterate through a SimpleXMLElementObject using PHP. However, I want to be able to do it *without* knowing the tag names in advance - I want a general solution that can be used as a discovery mechanism for the object's key names. I've tried a bunch of 'foreach' type solutions but can't get it to work.

Example code:

```
$schema = new SimpleXMLElement("<activity></activity>");
$schema->addAttribute("default-currency","asdf");
$schema->addAttribute("last-updated-datetime","jkl;");
$schema->addChild('title', 'example title');
```

print_r($schema) gives:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( 
        [default-currency] => asdf 
        [last- updated-datetime] => jkl; 
        ) 
    [title] => example title 
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `getName` function of SimpleXMLElement it will give you tag name

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php

example

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("xml file");

echo $sxe->getName() . "\n";

foreach ($sxe->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: and how does `getName` help in iterating the DOM tree?

Comment: @Gordon he has to do with `foreach` loop.

Comment: Right, but the OP - quoting - *"tried a bunch of 'foreach' type solutions but can't get it to work."* - your solution wont work either because it will only iterate the direct children of the root element and not the entire DOM tree.

Comment: @Gordon because ha hasn't used `getName` function.

Comment: No because the OP doesnt know how to traverse the DOM tree. And your solution does not show him/her how to do it either.

Comment: it will work when he used his logic with `getName` and `count`.

Comment: No, it won't. Your solution only works for `<a><b/></a>` but not for `<a><b><c/></b></a>` or any other DOM tree nested deeper than one level.

Comment: I believe the solution could work for nested objects if used recursively? However, it's only discovering child elements (e.g. "title"). Ideally what I need is to discover the array "@attributes" as well.

Comment: Ok, sorry, looked at the object reference and $sxe->attributes() should do it. Thanks! I know this was a simple question in retrospect, but it really helped me understand the difference between working with sxe and working with normal classes.