# what does means symbol "@" in this output?

Tags: php, simplexml

```
SimpleXMLElement Object(

 [ImageFormat] => SimpleXMLElement Object(

  [@attributes] => Array(

    [DimensionCategory] => small
    [Title] => extra  
  )

  [URL] => link..
 )
)
```

Comment: You need to explain where you got the output from!

Comment: Ok! This is an output generated by print_r() function.

Comment: Maybe it's just the name of the class-member…

Comment: Why haven't member "URL" got the symbol "@"?

Comment: URL is an element node, while the `@attributes` ... the name already telling you is attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@attributes` is derived from this

```
<ImageFormat DimensionCategory="small" Title="extra">
  <URL />
</ImageFormat>
```

in another word, is attributes of a given element

[see this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: but does symbol "@" means "ImageFormat's attributes"?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply part of the member name:

```
echo $xml->ImageFormat->{'@attributes'}['Title'];
```

You should use the `attributes()` method of the `SimpleXMLElement` class to access the attributes of an XML elment.

Answer (score 1):

As [knittl stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256396/what-does-means-symbol-in-this-output#7256500), it's just a member name. As a note: to access attributes in a SimpleXML node, instead of doing:

```
echo $xml->ImageFormat->{'@attributes'}['Title'];
```

One would do:

```
echo $xml->ImageFormat['Title'];
```