# Access @attributes data in SimpleXMLElement in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Just wanted to start by saying I **have** read a LOT of the questions on this site about this exact problem, but I'm still struggling to apply it to my scenario. If someone could help me out, that'd be great! :)

I am trying to extract data from the following XML:

```
$myXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products><product uri="https://192.168.110.201:9630/api/products/1807/" id="1807"    resource_type="current"><code>DEMO - MC700X/A</code><flags><inventoried>true</inventoried><editable_sell>false</editable_sell><master_model>false</master_model></flags><sell_price>0.00</sell_price><description>Apple MC700X/A Demo</description><inventory><available>7</available><reserved>0</reserved><coming_for_stock>2.0</coming_for_stock><coming_for_customer>0.0</coming_for_customer><warehouses>0</warehouses><total>7</total></inventory><product_photos/></product></products>';
```

I am using SimpleXML to put it into a PHP variable (object?) like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myXML);
```

If I do a:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following returned:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [product] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [uri] => https://192.168.110.201:9630/api/products/1807/
                    [id] => 1807
                    [resource_type] => current
                )

            [code] => DEMO - MC700X/A
            [flags] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [inventoried] => true
                    [editable_sell] => false
                    [master_model] => false
                )

            [sell_price] => 0.00
            [description] => Apple MC700X/A Demo
            [inventory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [available] => 7
                    [reserved] => 0
                    [coming_for_stock] => 2.0
                    [coming_for_customer] => 0.0
                    [warehouses] => 0
                    [total] => 7
                )

            [product_photos] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Now, when I try to access that data programatically, the following works fine:

```
// This returns the value as expected
echo '<pre>';
echo($xml->product->code);
echo '<br>';
echo($xml->product->sell_price);
echo '<br>';
echo($xml->product->inventory->available);
echo '<br>';
echo '</pre>';
```

This returns:

```
DEMO - MC700X/A
0.00
7
```

But I need to be able to access the "id" tag in the base "product" element (i.e. the @attributes bit), but can't work it out. I've been reading a lot, and figured that I should be able to use the attributes() method, but I can't work it out exactly.

Trying this didn't work:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo($xml->attributes());
echo '<br>';
echo '</pre>';
```

It just returns nothing. Can someone please help me? I want to be able to display the "id" tag.. i.e. what I would expect to be:

```
echo $xml['product']['@attributes']['id'];
```

obviously doesn't work either.

Thanks!!
John

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Did you try:

`echo (string)$xml->product->attributes()->id;`

That should give you access to the attributes.

If you have more than 1 product, it may be

`echo (string)$xml->product[0]->attributes()->id;`

You can also access the attributes using regular array notation such as:

```
$xml->product['id']; // instead of $xml->product->attributes()->id
```

See [Example #5](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5955) from the SimpleXML Examples as well as the manual page on [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) for more information.

Comment: Drew, you're the man! Thanks so much. I had tried that, but it looks like I needed to cast the result as a string for it to display I guess. :)

Comment: Yes, that can be annoying and easy to forget, if you access it without the cast, you should still get a value but it is a SimpleXMLElement so trying to use it in certain instances doesn't work right.

Comment: also take into account for using ['@attributes'] you need to cast the SimpleXMLElement to array first

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = (array)$obj;
$prop_id = $array['@attributes'];
```