# Access array returned from xpath in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

How can I access (in order to display) the elements returned by xpath?

My xpath call is

```
$products = $this->_dom->xpath('//menu/category[@name="'.$category.'"]');
```

and what I got is

```
    Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] 
=> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Tomato and Cheese ) [type] => 
Regular [available] => true [size] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] 
=> Array ( [name] => Small ) [price] => 5.50 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] 
=> Array ( [name] => Large ) [price] => 9.75 ) ) ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] 
=> Array ( [name] => Pepperoni ) [type] => Regular [available] => true [size] => Array ( [0] 
=> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Small ) [price] => 6.85 ) [1] 
=> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Large ) [price] => 10.85 ) ) ) 
) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Meatball ) [type] => Regular 
[available] => true [size] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array 
( [name] => Small ) [price] => 6.85 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array 
( [name] => Large ) [price] => 10.85 ) ) ) ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] 
=> Hawaiian ) [type] => Regular [available] => true [size] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement 
Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Small ) [price] => 7.95 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement 
Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Large ) [price] => 11.80 ) ) ) ) [4] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] => 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Three Aces Special ) [type] => 
Speciality [available] => true [size] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Small ) [price] => 9.80 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Large ) [price] => 15.80 ) ) ) ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement 
Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza ) [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Mediterranean ) [type] => Speciality [available] => true 
[size] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Small ) 
[price] => 9.80 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Large ) 
[price] => 15.80 ) ) ) ) )
```

What I want to do is to display this information in a sort of a list, so I'm wondering how can I access the elements of SimpleXMLElement Object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning up output:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => pizza )
    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => Tomato and Cheese ) 
        [type] => Regular 
        [available] => true 
        [size] => Array ( 
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                [@attributes] => Array ([name] => Small ) 
                [price] => 5.50 ) 
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [@attributes] => Array ([name] => Large ) 
                [price] => 9.75 ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Something like this will work, though a lot of your data is wrapped up as attributes, which will make it a little more verbose to get to, like the sizes attribute. You may need to cast items in order to get the value.

```
$products = $this->_dom->xpath('//menu/category[@name="'.$category.'"]');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    // accessing SimpleXML values is tricky
    // $name is a SimpleXMLElement Object
    $name = $product['title']; 

    // $name2 has the string value of the title attribute
    $name2 = (string) $product['title']; 

    // following works because __toString is implemented
    // by SimpleXMLElement class  
    echo "Title: " . $product['title']; 

    // alternative syntax, unless you cast to a 
    // string, you have a SimpleXML Object  
    $name3 =  $product->attributes()->title;
}
```

See [Access @attributes data in SimpleXMLElement in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523044/access-attributes-data-in-simplexmlelement-in-php)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, I had tried that before, but nothing, the result is blank. Any other idea? thanks

Comment: Maybe you have to cast the values. I don't know if that's only on older versions of SimpleXML or not.