# php simplexmlelement directly access element

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simple XML structure like, that when parse with `simplexml_load_string` generates this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [token] => rs2rglql9c8ztem
        )

    [attachments] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [attachment] => 112979696
        )
)
```

the XML structure:

```
<uploads token="vwl3u75llktsdzi">
  <attachments>
    <attachment>123456789</attachment>
  </attachments>
</uploads>
```

I can get to the only actually important value "123456789" through iteration but that is a faf. Is there a way I can access it directly, ideally using the names of the elements.

I need to able to get attributes to ideally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to store the textual node value of a `SimpleXMLElement` in its own variable is to cast the element to a string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$var = (string) $xml->attachments->attachment;
echo $var;
```

**UPDATE**

In accordance with the further question in your comment, the [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method will also return a `SimpleXMLElement` object which can be accessed in the same manner as the above solution. Consider:

```
$str = '<uploads token="vwl3u75llktsdzi">
  <attachments>
    <attachment myattr="attribute value">123456789</attachment>
  </attachments>
</uploads>';

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($str);
$attr = (string) $xml->attachments->attachment->attributes()->myattr;
echo $attr; // outputs: attribute value
```

Comment: Thanks sorry I should have asked this from the begging but is there an easy way to do this for the attributes too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can through the {} sytax here it goes:

```
$xmlString = '<uploads token="vwl3u75llktsdzi">
  <attachments>
    <attachment myattr="attribute value">123456789</attachment>
  </attachments>
</uploads>';

$xml  = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo "attachment attribute: " . $xml->{"attachments"}->attributes()["myattr"] " \n";
echo " uploads attribute: " . $xml->{"uploads"}->attributes()["token"] . "\n";
```

you can replace "attachments" with $myVar or something

remember attributes() returns an associative array so you can get the keys with php array_keys() or do a foreach cycle.