# PHP SimpleXML + Get Attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The XML I am reading looks like this:

```
<show id="8511">

    <name>The Big Bang Theory</name>
    <link>http://www.tvrage.com/The_Big_Bang_Theory</link>
    <started>2007-09-24</started>
    <country>USA</country>

    <latestepisode>
        <number>05x23</number>
        <title>The Launch Acceleration</title>
    </latestepisode>

</show>
```

To get (for example) The number of the latest episode, I would do:

```
$ep = $xml->latestepisode[0]->number;
```

This works just fine. But what would I do to get the ID from `<show id="8511">` ?

I have tried something like:

```
$id = $xml->show;
$id = $xml->show[0];
```

But none worked.

**Update**

My code snippet:

```
$url    = "http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episodeinfo.php?show=".$showName;
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

//still doesnt work
$id = $xml->show->attributes()->id;

$ep = $xml->latestepisode[0]->number;

echo ($id);
```

Ori. XML:

```
http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episodeinfo.php?show=The.Big.Bang.Theory
```

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml) - for the reference.

Comment: see :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537657/php-simplexml-get-attribute/19289857#19289857

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work.

```
$id = $xml["id"];
```

Your XML root becomes the root of the SimpleXML object; your code is calling a chid root by the name of 'show', which doesn't exist.

You can also use this link for some tutorials: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: This seems to do the trick! Thanks a lot! (I should probably take more time to look at the examples next time :( )

Answer (score 12):

You need to use [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

I believe this should work

```
$id = $xml->show->attributes()->id;
```

Comment: This would not work ... the `show` is the default root ... he need to warp the `xml` properly

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting `Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in....`

Answer (score 9):

This should work.
You need to use attributes with type (if sting value use (string))

```
$id = (string) $xml->show->attributes()->id;
var_dump($id);
```

Or this:

```
$id = strip_tags($xml->show->attributes()->id);
var_dump($id);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to get the attributes.

```
$id = $xml->show->attributes()->id;
```

You can also do this:

```
$attr = $xml->show->attributes();
$id = $attr['id'];
```

Or you can try this:

```
$id = $xml->show['id'];
```

Looking at the edit to your question (`<show>` is your root element), try this:

```
$id = $xml->attributes()->id;
```

OR

```
$attr = $xml->attributes();
$id = $attr['id'];
```

OR

```
$id = $xml['id'];
```

Comment: The first and second example unfortunately output `Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in....`, while the last one doesnt show anything at all.

Comment: It works, let me know in case you did edit @Sam´s answer too, because than I´d change the correct answer and choose yours now.

Comment: @Andrej: Nope Sam's answer was like that from the start :-P  I just edited the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$id = (int)$xml->show->attributes()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your `XML` properly and let it have examply using `<root></root>` or `<document></document>` anything .. see XML specification and examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<root>
<show id="8511">
    <name>The Big Bang Theory</name>
    <link>http://www.tvrage.com/The_Big_Bang_Theory</link>
    <started>2007-09-24</started>
    <country>USA</country>

    <latestepisode>
        <number>05x23</number>
        <title>The Launch Acceleration</title>
    </latestepisode>

</show>
</root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string ( $xml );
var_dump ($xml->show->attributes ()->id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have got no influence on how the xml is formatted!

Comment: I added the original XML source to my post!

Answer (score 0):

After you have correctly load the xml file using the SimpleXML objecto you can do a `print_r($xml_variable)` and you can easily find which attributes you can access.  As other users said `$xml['id']` also worked for me.