# how to get data from xml with attribute in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a XML file with following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<languages>
<language type="persian" abbr_type="fa">
    <menu>
        <home></home>
        <contact></contact>
        <about></about>
        <style></style>
    </menu>
    <title>
        <home></home>
        <contact></contact>
        <about></about>
        <style></style>
        <list></list>
        <biography></biography>
        <picture></picture>
        <movie></movie>
    </title>
    <about></about>
    <welcome></welcome>
</language>
<language type="english" abbr_type="en">
    <menu>
        <home></home>
        <contact></contact>
        <about></about>
        <style></style>
    </menu>
    <title>
        <home></home>
        <contact></contact>
        <about></about>
        <style></style>
        <list></list>
        <biography></biography>
        <picture></picture>
        <movie></movie>
    </title>
    <about></about>
    <welcome></welcome>
</language>
```

I wanna get **Title data** if attribute of language tag is "persian".

How can I get a series of data from XML, exactly? Is there any way to get data and put in an array?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php  | http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML + Get Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537657/php-simplexml-get-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get data and put in an array?

Yes, you can use DOMDocument > http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php . It create tree like structure in which you can easily find what are you looking for.

EXAMPLE

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($xmlString);
$xmlNodeArray = $xml->getElementsByTagName('language');
foreach ($xmlNodeArray as $element) {
    if($element->getAttribute('type') == "persian") {
         // do something with that element
    }
}
```