# XML Parsing / Get href attribute in title

Tags: php, xml, parsing, spotify

I want the *track-id* that is listed in the *href* attribute.

This is the spotify xml file:

```
http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Sportfreunde+Stiller+AND+track:Ein+Kompliment
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Sportfreunde+Stiller+AND+track:Ein+Kompliment";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->track as $track) {
    echo $track->name."<br>";
}
```

How to get in the upper hierarchy?

This is the desired output: `spotify:track:3ptJBraFGtaeprD4BHmTfV`. In my code I just put the name of the track in the output so that you can see that I am in the wrong hierarchy.

Comment: Upper hierarchy you mean to traverse deeper into the document tree? Check the [simplexml usage examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic), they demonstrate this pretty well and with examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML + Get Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537657/php-simplexml-get-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $track->attributes() instead of $track->name, it will output the value in the href attribute.

Ex:

```
<?php
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=Sportfreunde+Stiller+AND+track:Ein+Kompliment";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->track as $track) {
    echo $track->attributes() . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to use the href attribute in a other variable. In this way it would be nice to have a direct pointer to it

Comment: appending ->href to attributes() will only output value for href attribute. You can also access the tracks like this: $xml->track[0]->attributes()->href; Where [0] is the number of the track.

Comment: @MartinFranke: This answer also directly explains how you access attributes - with array-access and the attributes name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16306029/367456 - this is just a pick from the same day. Sure we already had this answered long ago. If you need a good answer, it's often better to use the search. Let me know if you've got more questions.

Answer (score 0):

do `print_r($xml)` and give what you get

It worked fine for me I got name or result like

```
Ein Kompliment
Ein Kompliment - Unplugged
Ein Kompliment - Unplugged
Ein Kompliment
Ein Kompliment
Ein Kompliment - Live aus der Olympiahalle MÃ¼nchen am 26.05.04
Ein Kompliment - Live aus der Olympiahalle MÃ¼nchen am 26.05.04
Ein Kompliment
Ein Kompliment (Tribute To Sportfreunde Stiller)
Ein Kompliment (Unplugged Karaoke Version) - Originally Performed By Sportfreunde Stiller
Ein Kompliment - Originally Performed By Sportfreunde Stiller
Ein Kompliment (Tribute To Sportfreunde Stiller)
Ein Kompliment - Originally Performed By Sportfreunde Stiller
Ein Kompliment (Karaoke Version) - Originally Performed By Sportfreunde Stiller
Ein Kompliment (Karaoke Version) - Originally Performed By Sportfreunde Stiller
```