# Parsing XML with PHP Not Working

Tags: php, xml

Why does `$xml->accommodation['id']` work but `$xml->information['items']` does not?

Here's my xml:

```
<information items="192">
<accommodation id="41457" code="7565E59E-77D8-4E24-8F40-85ABBB99CCD0"/>
<accommodation id="41597" code="1C858B57-F634-4FBB-877F-1D8831417A8B"/>
(etc.)
```

Here's my PHP:

```
$url = "URL TO XML FILE";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

(I'm VERY new to using xml. In case you couldn't tell!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML + Get Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537657/php-simplexml-get-attribute) - You find this explained in depth as well in the [SimpleXML Basic Usage examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic.php) - next to many other things. So before you try for too long next time, a look in there might give you some hints if not the solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `id` attribute of the first `accommodation` node, use;

```
$xml->accommodation['id']
```

To get the `items` attribute of the `information` node use;

```
$xml['items']
```

For example;

```
<?php

$str = '
  <information items="192">
    <accommodation id="30"/>
    <accommodation id="50"/>
    <accommodation id="80"/>
  </information>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$a = $xml->accommodation['id'];
$b = $xml['items'];

echo "$a, $b";    // Output: 30, 192

?>
```

The `->` means *children of* and can be chained eg; `$xml->foo->bar['id']`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. $xml['items'] is probably the only thing I didn't try!