# Get xml attribute using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

I am using a few third party APIs which returns errors via xml in the following form:

```
<xml>
<status>0</status>
<error code="111">Error message text goes here.</error>
</xml>
```

Using `simplexml_load_string` in PHP I can easily get the status 0 and the error message text but I cannot find a means of retrieving the `code="111"` value from the `<error code="111">`. It seems to get dropped by SimpleXML.

```
<?php
    $bytesRead = file_get_contents('http://api.....');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($bytesRead);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($xml); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Outputs

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status] => 0
    [error] => Error message text goes here.
)
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to obtain this value or can someone suggest another method to get this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's there but just doesn't show in the `print_r` output. Like [the basic examples page coins it in *Example #5 Using attributes*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic#example-5286):

> So far, we have only covered the work of reading element names and their values. SimpleXML can also access element attributes. Access attributes of an element just as you would elements of an [array](http://php.net/array).

Example:

```
$x = '<xml>
<status>0</status>
<error code="111">Error message text goes here.</error>
</xml>';

$attributeObject = simplexml_load_string($x)->error['code'];

print_r($attributeObject);
print_r((string) $attributeObject);
```

Program Output ([Demo](http://eval.in/6848))

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 111
)
111
```

Comment: saved life !      ..............

Comment: in case of` `[@attributes]` use this `$obj->attributes()->status`

Answer (score 3):

just use like this
echo $xml->error['code'];

eg:
http://codepad.org/uOqeBNz9