# Parsing complex XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following complex, not quite well-structured XML:

```
<event hometeam="K.Kanepi" awayteam="S.Lisicki" eventName="K.Kanepi-S.Lisicki" date="02/07/2013" time="14:05" datetime="2013-07-02T14:05:00+02:00">
    <subevent title="Match odds" dsymbol="MATCH_ODDS">
        <selection name="home" odds="3.1500" slipURL="URI/en/add-bet/3187-02072013,1"/>
        <selection name="away" odds="1.3500" slipURL="URI/en/add-bet/3187-02072013,2"/>
    </subevent>
```

I'm trying to parse it using this code:

```
$total_games = $xml->event->count();

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_games; $i++) {
    echo $xml->event[$i]->subevent.title;
```

$total games works correctly; however - when I try to parse subevent, I'm unsuccessful in getting the eventName, hometeam, date, etc.

Comment: Are you using DomDocument, SimpleXML or another library?

Comment: Appears to be SimpleXML by the syntax.

Comment: better try to fix the xml instead of tryign to force your DOM library to try and handle mal-formed input. If all it takes is appending `</event>` to that xml string to make it well-formed, then take that easy road.

Comment: It _might_ be easier with xpath. Give it a read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Comment: This XML is neither complex nor unstructured. It's just XML. Every XML parser can deal with it just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access attributes, you need to use array subscripting instead of class member syntax.  This works for me using your XML as input:

```
<?
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://some.url.here/gimme.xml');

    $total_games = $xml->event->count();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_games; $i++) {
        echo $xml->event[$i]->subevent['title'];
        //       Note the syntax here ^^^^^^^^^
    }
?>
```

PHP's [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) page is a good resource in this case.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but I'm not getting anything returned with that syntax?

Comment: Is the XML really malformed?

Comment: Here's the true location of the XML - I can't figure out how to parse it using simpleXML: http://odds.betgun.com/makeBB.php?id=WTA_WIMBLEDON