# extracting xml @attributes php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, attributes

I'm trying to extract data property[value] from xml, the $xml->xpath("/products") shows:

```
 [categories] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [category] => Zapas ) 

[properties] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
[property] => 
    Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
        Array ( 
            [name] => VAL) 
            [value] => 1111111 ) 
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
        Array ( 
            [name] => manufacturer ) 
            [value] => Nike) 
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
        Array ( 
            [name] => condition ) 
            [value] => new ) 
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
        Array ( 
            [name] => deliveryCosts ) 
            [value] => 0.00 ) 
    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
        Array ( 
            [name] => stock ) 
            [value] => in stock ) 
    ) )
```

I'm using next code for extracting xml values:

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_file("http://productType=2",'SimpleXMLElement'); 
foreach($xml->product as $file){ 
$file->categories->category; 
$file->properties????
}
```

The problem: I can't extract e.g Nike from:

```
[properties] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [property] => 
      Array ( 
         [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
              Array (
                 [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => 
                      Array ( 
                            [name] => manufacturer ) 
                            [value] => Nike)...
```

using

```
$brand= (string)$file->properties->property[1]->attributes()
```

I got manufacturer data (name), but

```
$brand= (string)$file->properties->property[1]->attributes()->value
```

doesn't works for getting Nike (value)

How could I get property[value] data?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$file->properties->property[1]->attributes[1]->attributes['value']`

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried but doesn't works    $brand=$file->properties->property[1]->attributes[1]->attributes['value']; I keep trying

Comment: Well I think [it might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexm) then.

Comment: I got it, the right way is : $brand= $file->properties->property[1]->{'value'};  @AedixRhinedale  tahnks for your help

Comment: great! Answer your own question, then. It might be useful for somebody PLUS you gain some rep points :)