# why ouput is blank when accessing simpleXML object?

Tags: php, xml

My simpleXMLElement output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[guid] => 2898580
[title] => England's doomed inevitability? 
[description] => 
[link] => http://www.espnfc.com/blog/the-match/60/post/2895340/roy-hodgson-rings-the-changes-but-england-struggle-again
[pubDate] => Jun 20, 2016 04:58 PM PDT
[enclosure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [length] => 150
                [url] => http://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i/?img=/photo/2016/0620/r94714_1296x729_16-9.jpg&w=100&h=80&scale=crop&site=espnfc
                [type] => image/jpeg
            )

    )

[category] => null
)
```

PHP 
with help of foreach loop when i print in it

```
 echo "Img_Url:".$img_url = $item->enclosure->attributes['url'] ;
```

it will show blank in there but i write this

```
echo "Img_Url:".$img_url = $item->enclosure->@attributes['url'] ;
```

it gives syntax error .

so how can i print this .

Comment: Looks to me like you'll need to surround the @ symbol with something like this: `echo "Img_Url:".$img_url = $item->enclosure->{"@attributes"}['url'];`

The @ symbol is used to suppress error messages in PHP.

Comment: SimpleXMLElement-objects always returns other objects. Try to cast it as string: `echo "Img_Url:".$img_url = (string) $item->enclosure->attributes['url']`

Comment: @Henders   not working still blank

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  not working

Comment: Did you try it with @Henders way of fetching the value and still cast it as a string?

Comment: When you say 'still blank' do you get  'Img_url:' printed or nothing at all? If you get nothing, then you'll need to look into your error logs..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  yeah but not working

Comment: @Henders  i get 'Img_url:'

Comment: Then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? I've just tried this out and I can access the `@` parameter in the way I suggested above..

Comment: @Henders   solution given in question as link give by Magnus . when i try your method it give show 'Img_url:' only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the attributes, you just need to treat the SimpleXMLElement object as an array. Don't go digging around in the object's internal structure.

```
 echo "Img_Url: " . (string) $item->enclosure['url'];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks ,  it is easy