# How to get image src with simplexml

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I want to parse image from a website and output into php file. I'm getting element by class and now i want to get it attribute src and then to print out the image. How can i achieve it?

```
$htmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDoc->loadHTML($result);

$simpleHtml = simplexml_import_dom($htmlDoc);
$image = $simpleHtml->xpath('//img[@class^="pdt-thumbnail-image"]@src');

foreach($image as $img) {
    echo '<img =src"'.$img[0].'">';
}
```

HTML Structure

```
<img role="presentation" class="pdt-thumbnail-image is-active lazy-image is-loaded" data-reactid="174" src="https://d2xngy2dw7hums.cloudfront.net/media/photos/products/2016/08/04/samsung_car_fast_charger_1470291965_408c5b7a.jpg">
```

Output error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: $image = $simpleHtml->xpath('//img[@class^="pdt-thumbnail-image"]/@src');

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml? The question would be better if you include sample XML so we can reproduce the current code.

Comment: @chris85 added!

Comment: Okay, and you need to use simplexml or you can just use domdocument? A domdocument approach, https://eval.in/789700.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your error logs, or turn on `display_errors` on your development environment, you should see a warning that the XPath evaluation failed, because `[@class^="pdt-thumbnail-image"]` is not valid XPath. (Note that the XML library PHP uses only supports XPath 1.0.)

Instead, you should use [the `starts-with` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with), or probably more useful for matching a class, [the `contains` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```
 $simpleHtml->xpath('//img[contains(@class, "pdt-thumbnail-image")]/@src');
```

Note also that you were missing the `/` in `/@src`.