# PHP How to read child elements of XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I assume there is a very simple answer to this.

XML looks like:

```
<ORDERSTATUS>
      <DATE>10/03/17</DATE>
      <INVOICE>abc</INVOICE>
      <INVTOTAL Tax="15.00" Freight="18" SubTotal="100.00">133.0</INVTOTAL>
<ORDERSTATUS>
```

Using `simple_xml_load_string` does not return the `Tax`, `Freight` or `SubTotal`elements. It just shows `Invoice`

```
[DATE] => 10/03/17 
[INVOICE] => abc 
[INVTOTAL] => 133.0
```

How do I retrieve those inner values?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your xml should end with a closing `</ORDERSTATUS>`

[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) returns a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) which has a method [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) from which you can get "Tax" etc..

For example:

```
$string = <<<XML
<ORDERSTATUS>
    <DATE>10/03/17</DATE>
    <INVOICE>abc</INVOICE>
    <INVTOTAL Tax="15.00" Freight="18" SubTotal="100.00">133.0</INVTOTAL>
</ORDERSTATUS>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo $xml->INVTOTAL->attributes()->Tax;
```

Which will give you:

15.00

[Output](https://3v4l.org/IXkbF)

Answer (score 0):

You can access this using `attributes` .First select `INVTOTAL` then select this `attributes` like tax so this is normal process

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<ORDERSTATUS>
    <DATE>10/03/17</DATE>
    <INVOICE>abc</INVOICE>
    <INVTOTAL Tax="15.00" Freight="18" SubTotal="100.00">133.0</INVTOTAL>
</ORDERSTATUS>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo "DATE:".$xml->DATE."<br>";
echo "INVOICE:".$xml->INVOICE ."<br>";
echo "INVTOTAL:".$xml->INVTOTAL ."<br>";
echo  "Tax:".$xml->INVTOTAL->attributes()->Tax."<br>";
echo  "Freight:".$xml->INVTOTAL->attributes()->Freight."<br>";
echo  "SubTotal:".$xml->INVTOTAL->attributes()->SubTotal."<br>";
```

then this is output :

```
DATE:10/03/17
INVOICE:abc
INVTOTAL:133.0
Tax:15.00
Freight:18
SubTotal:100.00
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php