# How do I print Attribute Values of an object(stdClass) in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to print out an attribute value of an object.  The particular example I am working from is this:

```
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["links"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total-matched"]=>
      string(2) "31"
      ["records-returned"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["page-number"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
```

I want to print the value of the links total-matched (which is 31).  I've tried this:  `echo $object->links->total-matched;` but I only get the value of 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you try get set methods.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$object->links->total-matched` evaluates as `$object->link->total - matched` (`-` is minus, I suppose you should see warning about using unknown constant - turn on error reporting). To access attributes with names like this you can do following: `$object->links->{'total-matched'}` although in this case, since it's SimpleXML attribute, I think you need to get attributes array:

```
$attr = $object->links->attributes();
echo $attr['total-matched'];
```