# PHP Accessing SimpleXML data in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array saved in a variable title `$data`. I want to grab or echo the value of `@attributes`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Soekarno
    [1] => Dr.(H.C.) Ir. H. Soekarno1 (ER, EYD: Sukarno, nama lahir: Koesno Sosrodihardjo) (lahir di Surabaya, Jawa Timur, 6 Juni 1901 – meninggal di Jakarta, 21 Juni 1970 pada umur 69 tahun) adalah Presiden pertama  Republik Indonesia yang menjabat pada periode 1945–1967.:11, 81 Ia memainkan peranan penting dalam memerdekakan bangsa Indonesia dari penjajahan Belanda.:26-32 Ia adalah Proklamator Kemerdekaan Indonesia (bersama dengan Mohammad Hatta) yang terjadi pada tanggal 17 Agustus 1945. Soekarno adalah yang pertama kali mencetuskan konsep mengenai Pancasila sebagai dasar negara Indonesia dan ia sendiri yang menamainya.Soekarno menandatangani Surat Perintah 11 Maret 1966 Supersemar yang kontroversial, yang isinya —berdasarkan versi yang dikeluarkan Markas Besar Angkatan Darat— menugaskan Letnan Jenderal Soeharto untuk mengamankan dan menjaga keamanan negara dan institusi kepresidenan.
    [2] => https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soekarno
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [source] => https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Presiden_Sukarno.jpg/35px-Presiden_Sukarno.jpg
                    [width] => 35
                    [height] => 50
                )    
        )    
)
```

I tried using `$data[3]->@attributes`, but got an error

Comment: per the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) - try `$data[3]->attributes()->source`

Comment: See if this answers your Question: [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)