# Parsing very simple XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

Very simple request (I think) that I have had no luck with.

Here is the contents of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<status USER_ID="xxxxx">OK</status>
```

Current php:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
```

Outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [USER_ID] => xxxxx ) [0] => OK )
```

And now I'm stuck

How can I get the value of USER_ID and that the status was "OK" into my php script.

Thanks.

Comment: `(string) $xml->attributes()->USER_ID` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Comment: ```$user_id=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml))->getElementsByTagName("status")->item(0)->getAttribute("USER_ID");
$text=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml))->getElementsByTagName("status")->item(0)->textContent;
var_dump($user_id,$text);```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below

```
echo "Display the user id: " . $xml['USER_ID'];
echo "Display the status: " . $xml[0];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like SimpleXml (like me), you can also use the XMLReader Class like:

```
$XMLReader = new XMLReader;
$XMLReader->XML(file_get_contents($file)); //you can use $XMLReader->open('file://'.$file); too
//move to first node
$XMLReader->read();
//get an attribute
echo "USER_ID:".$XMLReader->getAttribute('USER_ID')."\n";
//get the contents of the tag as a string
echo "Status:" .$XMLReader->readString();
```

Output:

```
USER_ID:xxxxx
Status:OK
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/948758d10869ef23113a9106cc8eb4df9eafea17)