# Get all values inside quotes in php string

Tags: php

I have the following string:

```
<data value="https://thisurl.com">One description</data>
<data value="https://thaturl.com">Another description</data>
```

I want to display only the text inside the double quotes, in this case the urls. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/".*?"|\'.*?\'/', $input, $array);
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

This code extracts the urls from the string but is adding single quotes and I need the plain url without single or double quotes:

'https://thisurl.com'
'https://thatsurl.com'

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You can use simplexml to parse your xml instead of a regex : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Will it always be `value="STRING"`?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes, that's correct, the format will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?

Use PHP's [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) parser to do the job;

```php
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_string('<xml>
        <data value="https://thisurl.com">One description</data>
        <data value="https://thaturl.com">Another description</data>
    </xml>');
    foreach($xml as $node) {
        $url = (String) $node->attributes();
        echo $url . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Output:

```
https://thisurl.com
https://thaturl.com
```

---

Based on comment (same output);

```php
<?php

    $data_1 = '<data value="https://thisurl.com">One description</data>';
    $data_2 = '<data value="https://thaturl.com">Another description</data>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string('<xml>' . $data_1 . $data_2 . '</xml>');
    foreach($xml as $node) {
        $url = (String) $node->attributes();
        echo $url . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: Will this require to add the XML tags at the beginning and end of the string? These string items are passed through a variable, they're not actually in the same php doc.

Comment: @Ken, Yes, `simplexml_load_string` only accepts valid XML. You could so something like this: `$xml = simplexml_load_string('<xml>' . $var1 . $var2 . '</xml>')`;

Comment: Thanks, this method is better than my initial "rookie" attempt. I guess ```$node->attributes();``` gets all attributes? If so, in case more attributes are added; Can I do ```$node->attributes()->{'value'};```?

Comment: Yea, if there are more attributes you can extract them. Take a look at [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Comment: Great! I'm going with your answer. Thank you. PS: I don't get why my question was downvoted.

Comment: @Ken I guess the downvotes are caused by the lack of information. If you'd add the fact that you're dealing with xml and explain why you're trying to extract those url the question would be a bit better. However, in my opinion StackOverflow isn't that polite to new users, it's hard to find out how to improve a question/answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the format is always the same, your regex could be as simple as `value="(.*)"`. In this case, `match 1` will always be the URL.

```
$input = '<data value="https://thisurl.com">One description</data>
<data value="https://thaturl.com">Another description</data>';

preg_match_all('/value="(.*)"/', $input, $array);
foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
https://thisurl.com
https://thaturl.com
```