# php simplexml find value of a specific field

Tags: php, simplexml

The XML, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?> 
    - <Tables>
        - <Table name="I_BOOKING">
            - <Row action="UPDATE" success="Y">
              <Field name="AUTOBOOK">888800</Field> 
              <Field name="TOUROP">01</Field> 
              <Field name="REFERENCE">GSDFFD</Field> 
              <Field name="NBPAX">2</Field> 
              <Field name="NBINF">1</Field> 
              </Row>
      </Table>
      - <Table name="I_EXCDATERESA">
          - <Row action="UPDATE" success="Y">
               <Field name="EXCURS">KNO</Field> 
               <Field name="DATE">2012-04-12</Field> 
               <Field name="BOOKNR">125445</Field> 
               <Field name="NAME">TEST 12/4</Field> 
               <Field name="PICKUPTIME">00:00:00</Field> 
           </Row>
         - <Row action="UPDATE" success="Y">
               <Field name="EXCURS">KNO</Field> 
               <Field name="DATE">2012-04-13</Field> 
               <Field name="BOOKNR">14574575</Field> 
               <Field name="NAME">TEST 13/4</Field> 
               <Field name="PICKUPTIME">00:00:00</Field> 
          </Row>
       </Table>
    </Tables>
```

When I treat the table `I_EXCDATERESA`, I need to get the value of Field `BOOKNR`, so `125445` or `14574575` in this example, according to the row I am dealing with and load it in `$autobook`:

```
...

$simplexml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

foreach ($simplexml->Table as $value)
{
    $tableName = $value->attributes()->name;
    foreach ($value->Row as $value)
    {
        if ($tableName == 'I_EXCDATERESA')
        {
            if ($value->Field->attributes()->name == 'BOOKNR')
            {
            $autoBook = $value->Field;
```

This is not working, `$autobook` is not loaded, as it is not on the first 'Field' but on the third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this, it worked for me:

```
foreach ($simplexml->Table as $value)
{
    $tableName = $value->attributes()->name;
    foreach ($value->Row as $value_1)
    {
        if ($tableName == 'I_EXCDATERESA')
        {
            foreach ($value_1->Field as $value_2)
            {
                if ($value_2->attributes()->name == 'BOOKNR')
                {
                    $autoBook = $value_2[0];
                    echo $autoBook;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your problem is with:

```
 $value->Field->attributes()->name=='BOOKNR'
```

That's too much: I added another cycle on each field of elemts Row!

Comment: Ok! so just because you are new to Stack Overflow accept the answer as the correct one, mine and also yours reputation will improve. Thanks :-)

Comment: There also is a logical flaw on testing for the table name, it should be done right after the tablename is read, not inside a deeper level of indentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use case for XPath:

```
$search = $simplexml->xpath('/Tables/Table[name="I_EXCDATERESA"]/Row/Field[name="BOOKNR"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

well there are couple of ways to approach this situation

1. using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
2. using the attribute() function inside simplexml which was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256796/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-from-xml-file-in-php)
3. and probably the easiest option is noticing that BOOKNER is the third node in every Row
   I would do something like this.

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($simplexml->->children()); $i++){
       echo $simplexml->Table[$i]->Table->Field[2];
   }

good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$simplexml->xpath('/Tables/Table[name="I_EXCDATERESA"]/Row/Field[name="BOOKNR"]');
```

does'nt work, you missed the @

```
$simplexml->xpath('/Tables/Table[@name="I_EXCDATERESA"]/Row/Field[@name="BOOKNR"]');
```