# Php : simplexml - Getting attribute value

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">

<title>iphone cover 4</title>

<media:price>$35.95</media:price>

<media:thumbnail url="http://rlv.zcache.com/22.jpg"/>

<media:content url="http://rlv.zcache.com/440.jpg"/>
```

Above is the xml file I want to read, I can get **title**, **media price** and even **Guid's isPermalink** attribute. But I cannot get **media:thumbnail attribute**
Below is my code.

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $cool)
{
    $per = $cool->guid["isPermaLink"];
    $thumb = $cool->children('media', true)->price;
    $title = $cool->title;
    $thumb = $cool->children('media', true)->thumbnail["url"];
}
```

How do I get **media:thumbnail attribute**?

Comment: go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256796/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-from-xml-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cycle through thumbnail attributes

```
foreach ($cool->children('media', true)->thumbnail as $thumb) {
   $URL = $thumb['url']
}
```