# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xml reading?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

When I try to read from an XML, foreach react as **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** The XML file

[XML File](http://www.medhyaftravel.com/api/api3/api/myxmlfile1.xml)

Following code is used to retrieve data

```
        $availabilityrs = simplexml_load_string($response3);
        $hotel = $availabilityrs->rooms->room;
        $hotel1 = $availabilityrs->rooms->room;
        foreach ($hotel1 as $room) {
           echo "<b>Room Name: </b>".$room['name']."</br>"; 
        }
```

Comment: update $room['name'] to $room->name;

Comment: Please look on the xml also, link is attached. Name is an attribute

Comment: can you print_r($hotel1); ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of an attribute from XML file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256796/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-from-xml-file-in-php)

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1256844/689579 - `$rm = $room->attributes();  echo "<b>Room Name: </b>".$rm['name']."</br>"; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add `hotel` to your assign variable.

try this;

```
$availabilityrs = simplexml_load_string($response3);
$hotel = $availabilityrs->hotel->rooms->room; // add hotel
$hotel1 = $availabilityrs->hotel->rooms->room; // add hotel

foreach ($hotel1 as $room) {
    echo "<b>Room Name: </b>".$room['name']."</br>"; 
}
```